# ionic-native media with capacitor callbackId: INVALID

Tags: android, cordova, media, capacitor, ionic-native

@ionic-native/media not working with android when create and play sound :

The package.json :

```
//dependencies
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^5.36.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.3",

//devDependencies
    "@capacitor/android": "3.0.0-rc.4",
```

The message on Android Studio

```
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: INVALID, service: Media, action: create, actionArgs: ["b2d55f8b-ec9f-9e5a-4bb3-66d1230e1cc0","\/assets\/sounds\/catHurt.wav"]
```

Note that it perfectly work with IOS.